# } expected UNITY C# ЧТО ДЕЛАТЬ?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я писал код, для врагов в своей игре что бы они двигались по ВейПоинтам и в строке 23 какаято непонятная ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И многие скажут: поставь } там где надо
Но во первых: Юнити просит поставить этот знак за 5 "Пробелов" до основного кода
И да, я ставил этот знак но ошибка не проподала и появлялись еще ошибки.
Помогите плизз

Comment: Тебе самому-то удобно писать и разбираться в неотформатированном коде?

Comment: "какаято непонятная ошибка" --- самое точно описание ошибки всех времён. За такое нобеля надо давать))  Текст-то точной и полный ошибки где? Точно в этом файле?

Comment: " И да, я ставил этот знак но ошибка не проподала и появлялись еще ошибки" -- какие? ты уверен, что это не ошибки некорректного кода, а не того, что теперь есть скобка?  Ну и на приведённом скрине показывает "Проблемы не найдены"

Comment: "ЧТО ДЕЛАТЬ?" - предлагаю бросать программирование и идти в школу. Серьезно: "какаято", ""во первых", "проподала", запятых нет, точек нет, хотя начало нового предложения очевидно прослеживается по заглавной букве! Одним словом, я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса.

Comment: Слушайте мне 11 лет и я только начал программировать. И если учитывать мое плохое зрение (я в старых очках) то допущение такой ошибки должно было произойти)

Comment: @SaphirdGamer У меня плохое зрение, я прогаю без очков, но поближе к монику.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯   А возраст так вообще тут причём не ясно

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в приведённом коде явно не в `}`. Если она и была, то на скрине её нет.

А вот где есть ошибка, так это в `Lenght`. А нужно `Length`

Удивителен тот факт, что при разработке в *IDE*  при наличии **автодополнения** человек допускает такую ошибку :-)

Comment: Извеняюсь за такую глупость, просто я только начал программировать и так же спасибо за помощь

Comment: Я исправил опечатку, но ошибка не пропала

Comment: @SaphirdGamer  прочитай коммент в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1313913/191482  и удаляй вопрос.   И прежде чем писать на Юнити, вначала освой базы языка, в т.ч. как пишутся методы. + используй автодополнение IDE и варианты исправления кода, которые оно (IDE) предлагает.  Плюс используй переводчик для перевода ошибок.